# List array of array of struct

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

First, I declared two structure like the following:

```
struct m1
{
  int 
  int 
  char
  ...
}
```

and

```
struct m2
{
  int 
  int 
  char
  ...
}
```

I have two arrays of m1 and m2. I need to map one m1 against to multiple  m2. I don't Know the size of both, so after I search I decide to use

```
List<m1 or m2> = new List<m1 or m2>();
```

and works fine.
but

```
List<m1 , m2> = new List<m1 , m2>();
```

gives me error "require one type argument"
Please help me, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is vague, doesn't compile and makes no sense. Please try clarifying what you mean with a small yet complete reproduce of your problem.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, why is vague, yes it doesn't compile code. but I need the way to do something in my code like declare list of array of array of type struct. is it a rule in stack-overflow, must put compiling code? please clarify for me.

Comment: Yes, it is. I suggest you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, thanks, the problem solved, and I need to delete my question because I think it's illegal here. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) requires one Type it cannot have two types ,what I see is you need to map one `m1` against multiple `m2`, so in this case [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) is suitable here:

```
Dictionary<m1 , List<m2>> = new Dictionary<m1 , List<m2>>();
```

and now add items in dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I need. may be I am new and don't know Dictionary.